# setting the font size for page number in memoir class

Tags: header-footer, memoir, fontsize, page-numbering

The requirement for my document is to have times new roman font type with font size of 12 at the main body and size 8 for page number.

I'm new to latex and I've looked it up in the documentation for memoir class but got even more confused than ever as I found different class option for different types of text size and options as shown in Table 3.7 of the attached linked documentation.

http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf

Can anyone please enlighten me on this matter? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the standard `memoir` headings, it suffices to add these lines in your preamble:

```
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\scriptsize\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\scriptsize\thepage}{}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\scriptsize\thepage}{}{\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\slshape\rightmark}{}{\scriptsize\thepage}
```

In fact, if you don't specify otherwise the page styles used by `memoir` are `empty`, `plain`, and `headings`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\scriptsize\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\scriptsize\thepage}{}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\scriptsize\thepage}{}{\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\slshape\rightmark}{}{\scriptsize\thepage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you. you've been great help. Now I understand better :)

Comment: @user46182 You're welcome. Happy to help.